# Run checks on drupal_goto function

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms, drupal-webform, drupal-form-validation

I have a strange issue with a drupal site and a custom form. I have a custom module that puts a form as a block...simple input field that posts a search query to a store locator.

The form keeps getting overridden and the action/url changes randomly at random times. I need a quick solution to this whilst we debug the real issue that's causing this.

I need to write an if statement that checks the drupal_goto function that goes along the lines of if drupal_goto == /store-locator then run else change the drupal_goto action to /store-locator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - if you need to patch drupal_goto temporarily then do so, if not, what do you need to know?

Comment: drupal_goto('store-locator', array('query' => $query));

@Clive The function above gets overridden and the url 'store-locator' changes for some unknown reason. How can I run a check to make sure that store-locator doesn't change and if it does revert it back?

Comment: If this is in a form submission, use `$form_state['redirect'] = 'path';` instead. If you already have a `destination` parameter in the URL, that will take precedence over everything. If that's happening, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5440/form-redirect-not-working-if-destination-is-in-url-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks @Clive - I have applied your suggestions. I will keep update this question if it works.